# Show contents of a zip file in a WebView

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, webkit

I want to have a WebView that displays some static files from the application bundle. Since I have a large number of small files, I'd like to pack them all into a compressed archive so the application doesn't take up too much space. What's the best way to make this happen?

Comment: Just a thought: Does WebKit support Safari Web archives?

Comment: @Bavarious: I don't know, but I'll find out. It seems like this approach has got potential.

Answer (score 0):

This should help you out: http://code.google.com/p/ziparchive/

To display data in the WebView:

On Mac OS X use [WebFrame](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/WebKit/Classes/WebFrame_Class/Reference/Reference.html)'s `loadHTMLString:baseURL:`

On iOS use [UIWebView](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIWebView_Class/Reference/Reference.html)'s `loadHTMLString:baseURL:`

Comment: Well, this answers part of the question. Unfortunately, it doesn't answer the hard part: how to get WebKit to load the files that are inside the archive. (I could unpack the archive to the file system first, but that totally defeats the purpose.)

Comment: What kind of files are you trying to display in the WebView?

Comment: Just normal web stuff. HTML, CSS, Javascript, images.

Answer (score 0):

What you probably want to do, is implement an NSURLProtocol subclass that will resolve relative URLs by reading them from the zip archive. That way, you only need to initially read the "main" HTML file from the zip into memory, and the others will be read in on demand. To get WebKit to use your custom URL protocols for resolving relative paths, you could instantiate the WebView like this:

```
[[web_view mainFrame] loadHTMLString:your_main_html baseURL:[[NSURL alloc] initWithString:@"zip:///"]];
```

Apple has a really good example of combining a custom URL protocol with a WebView here:

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#samplecode/SpecialPictureProtocol/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS10003816